# Limit execution time of PHP imagecreatefromjpeg() function when using external images

Tags: php, image, gd

When using `imagecreatefromjpeg()` and passing it a URL to an external image ( fetching 10 images per page, since pagination is set ), it works on pages 1-7 for example and fetches the images correctly, but when it comes to page 8 in most cases, it needs about 2 minutes to execute fetching of 10 images for that page and gives this error:
[Php error for imagecreatefromjpeg()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN1r0.png)

I've googled this issue the whole day and found out that in most cases, the issue is the remote host that serves these images. It is either slow or has some missconfigurations on it.

Now, I have setup displaying a default image if the image is not fetched through this PHP function, however, code still runs for about 2 minutes on page 8 for example, slowing down the website considerably.

My question is: is it possible to limit the execution time of `imagecreatefromjpeg()` PHP function so that it only runs for 1 or 2 seconds and stops if it doesn't fetch the image by that timeframe ?

Comment: so what's different about page 8 v.s. the other pages? gd itself couldn't care less what "page" you're on. it just loads up an image and does stuff with it. and no, you can't really control timeouts with GD. since it's an external library, php is basically just acting as a translation layer. every gd call will block until it's done.

Comment: I see :) Thanks a lot for your time ! The only difference I can spot is that it kinda pulls in "larger" images than the pages before it, but not too big that it should cause our of memory issues or something...

Comment: what's your definition of "larger". remember that a "simple" 100kb .jpg image can expand to many gigabytes of in-memory storage. gd doesn't work with jpg data, it works with bitmaps, and loading a high-resolution image can suck up a LOT of memory.

Comment: Larger as in " 900x600 px" for example, instead of about 2 times smaller ones on previous page(s)

Answer (score 1):

As @marc-b commented, you can't directly control the timeout.

How I would do it:

1. Main webpage kicks off background script
2. Background script fetches the images and converts
3. Main webpage waits for a second or two (maybe milliseconds, in a loop) and checks to see if the converted image is ready. If not, respond with the alternate fallback image.

That way your webpage won't slow down too much. And yet the background script will still ultimately finish converting the image so that it's reach next time you need it.

Comment: Would the "background" script be a PHP script, or did you have AJAX call in mind ?

Comment: I assumed a PHP script. Figure you'd want to kick it off during the initial webpage load, which means this is happening server-side (rather than client-side with ajax).